# Multi-level top navigation menu on the application/_layouts pages

Tags: master-page, custom-masterpage

I created custom master page, and I created feature for top navigation menu. My custom master page works fine, but not on the application/_layouts pages; viewlsts.aspx, settings.aspx, etc.. I only see one level, I can't see the other levels as I customized in my master page. How can I see them?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The application pages from SharePoint do not inherit the top navigation of the master pages, they use their own top navigation.

Here is the aspx code from the settings page.

```
<%@ Register TagPrefix="wssuc" TagName="TopNavBar" src="~/_controltemplates/TopNavBar.ascx" %>
<asp:Content contentplaceholderid="PlaceHolderTopNavBar" runat="server">
    <wssuc:TopNavBar id="IdTopNavBar" runat="server" Version="4" ShouldUseExtra="true"/>
</asp:Content>
```